# Serializing WPF DrawingBrush with protobuf-net problems

Tags: .net, wpf, serialization, protobuf-net

There is a need to serialize some BL structure that contains DrawingBrush. I've rewritten it as follows :

```
[ProtoContract]
public class BaseProtoBuf : INotifyPropertyChanged, IFormattable
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    // Bunch of properties of .net primitive types
    // ..
    private DrawingBrush _geometry;
    [ProtoMember(9)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public DrawingBrush Geometry
    {
            get { return _geometry; }
            set
            {
                _geometry = value; 
                ScaleDrawing();
            }
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(string))]
// All other includes
[ProtoInclude(9, typeof(DrawingBrush)]
public class DerivedProtoBuf : BaseProtoBuf, ICloneable
{        
    // Some additional properties of primitive types, annotated starting with ProtoMember 10 and so on
}
```

To serialize i'm executing following code :

```
const string fileName = "Protobuf.bin";
using (var file = File.Create(fileName))
{
    file.Position = 0;
    var testBase = new BaseProtoBuf
                                   {
                                      Height = 100,
                                      Width = 100,
                                      Name = "Test 1",
                                      OffsetX = 200,
                                      OffsetY = 200,
                                      Geometry = sourceList[0].Geometry // some not-null DrawingBrush
                                  };
    Serializer.Serialize(file, testBase);
    file.Position = 0;
    var restored = Serializer.Deserialize<BaseProtoBuf>>(file);
}
}
```

I need to serialize Derived class object, but during Base serialization i get *"No suitable Default DrawingBrush encoding found"*. Thought it's because DrawingBrush can be null for some objects, but in test one it isn't. Any workarounds to properly serialize 1) Base object with not-null DrawingBrush 2) Derived object with null DrawingBrush ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct RuntimeTypeModel configuration for serializing of simple WPF Brush :

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Brush), false)
               .AddSubType(300, typeof(SolidColorBrush));
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(SolidColorBrush), false)
                .Add("Color");
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Color), false)
                .Add("A", "R", "G", "B"); // needed for proper color serialization
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(SolidColorBrush), false)
        .Add("Color");
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(DrawingBrush), false)
        .Add("Stretch", "Drawing");
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Drawing), false)
        .AddSubType(100, typeof(DrawingGroup))
        .AddSubType(200, typeof(GeometryDrawing));
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(DrawingGroup), false)
        .Add("Children");
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Pen), false)
        .Add("Brush", "Thickness", "LineJoin");
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(GeometryDrawing), false)
       .Add("Brush", "Geometry", "Pen");
```

Comment: eesh that looks like.... "fun" ;p glad there was a way through, though. Minor feedback; because of how "varint" encoding works, using smaller tag-numbers for the sub-types (the 300/200/100) should save a few bytes. Nothing jaw-dropping, though.

Answer (score 2):

The DrawingBrush is not immediately Serializable since the contract is not defined. Various options here:

- if the type is fairly simple, you could configure a contract at runtime via RuntimeTypeModel, adding in the properties/sub-types etc as needed
- in some cases, using a "surrogate" may be preferred - a type with bidirectional conversion operators used to act as an on-the-fly DTO - again, a surrogate can be specified via RuntimeTypeModel; a "surrogate" let's you use your existing model, but swapping in DTO types as needed
- otherwise, consider avoiding framework-specific types in the model, and just use DTO types with the information you need. From that *construct* the desired value for your framework at runtime

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I think I need to choose option #1 because there is a requirement to store objects "as-is" (actually, what i get for building them is plain xml from external source with bunch of strings, so creating managed objects and then serialize them back to strings is not an option) for quick load afterwards. Can you point to some example of contract configuration for complex framework datatypes?

Comment: I've checked out the whole repository and dug a bit into serializers, but as IProtoSerializer is internal I guess it is not meant to be implemented outside of library. Also tried RuntimeTypeModel manual creation for underlying type, but it didn't help either (error in Compile - BuildAllSerializers : MetaType object has null Serializer that causes *No serializer defined for type : System.Windows.Media.DrawingBrush* error).

Comment: @Jaded RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(DrawingBrush), false).Add("x", "y", "z"); for example - much more subtle setups are possible.

Comment: Thanks, this approach might exactly what i need.I've manually set up DrawingBrush, and it serializes all properties. The only problem is deserialization that throws TargetInvocationException. I debugged the process step-by-step and found out that problem is in encoding - while invoking Geometry's Parse method in ParseableSerializer (Read method, line 57) source string is "F1M0,499938;0,499959L23,8304;0,499959 23,8304;18,4977 0,499938;18,4977 0,499938;0,499959z" when (in my locale?) it was "F1M0.499938,0.499959L23.8304,0.499959 23.8304,18.4977 0.499938,18.4977 0.499938,0.499959z"

Comment: @Jaded what are the locales of the two ends there?

Comment: Application itself is platform-independent, but on development machine locale is "RU-ru". So i guess during serialization protobuf-net uses invariant culture that breaks further deserialization. Looking for fix in case specific method (Geometry.Parse) doesn't accept encoding. If universal approach is not possible, one that considers both server and client have russian locale is acceptable.

Comment: @Jaded indeed protobuf-net tries to use invariant where it can; it might be that in that case, a surrogate is the best option - then you do the parse etc any which way specifying whatever optional parameters are necessary to make it work robustly

Comment: As i see my procedure will be "perform protobuf-net serialization with explicit EN-us culture specified". At least when i do it manually, i.e. Thread.CurrentThread.CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("EN-us"); Serializer.Serialize(file, testData); Thread.CurrentThread.CultureInfo = myOldSavedCultureInfo; everything seems to be working. How can i implement it in terms of protobuf-net Surrogates? I see only SetSurrogate(Type) method in MetaType and have no clue how to use it so far. And even if you don't have time to do that, huge thanks. Raw and spiky, but this solution may be sufficient.

Comment: @Jadd this is a basic example of a surrogate type: `[ProtoContract]
class SomeSurrogate
{
    public static implicit operator SomeType(SomeSurrogate value)
    {
        return new SomeType { /* from value.Value, etc */ };
    }
    public static implicit operator SomeSurrogate(SomeType value)
    {
        return new SomeSurrogate { Value = /* from value.blah */ };
    }
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}`

Comment: Ok, will try this approach later. Can you look at my self-answer above? I've edited it to outline a new problem with Brushes. This time i guess it's purely my fault because of incorrect configuration of RTM.